# How to install magento 2.4.x with NGINX on ubuntu?

Tags: magento2.4

Please give me steps to install magento 2.4.x.

Thanks,
Ziya

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the Magneto doc link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html.
This is the Magento Way to install with nginx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Arun

I followed following steps:

Magento 2.4.1 installation steps

1 - Install PHP 7.4 With Nginx (Try to run info.php)

2 - Install Maria DB with supported version

3 - Install Elasticsearch

4 - Configure NGINX host

"5 - Setup Magento using below command

/usr/bin/php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://dev.m241.com/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=m241 --db-user=dbuser --db-password=dbpass123 --admin-firstname=Ziya --admin-lastname=Khan --admin-email=ziya@mailinator.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1

"